# Can’t get url_to_postid to work

Tags: php

Why does url_to_postid return 0 here?

```
$url = 'https//devapps.somedomain.edu/hr/no-permissions-message/';
```

(I changed the domain before posting btw)

```
$post_id = url_to_postid($url);
```

I guess I don’t understand how it’s supposed to work. That is a valid page/URL, but no id is being returned. It’s not a page of blog posts, maybe that’s the problem?? If so, is there a way to get the ID of a page (not blog posts), given a URL?

Thanks,
Doug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably because you don't have a colon in the url after `https` (assuming you copied the `$url` parameter correctly).

The function will return a '0' if the page does not exist.

Comment: Yup.  That was it.   I added the protocol but didn't add a colon.

Comment: Glad that was it. I call those "SAF" (Smack Against Forehead) errors. Also known as "DOH!".  :)